# library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services, ocr

I am trying to work with image processing project , i use Firebase Database,when i am trying to add play-services-vision in dependancies it comes up eith ERROR that is 'The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.'

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:16.2.0'
```

Please make sure you have the following line of code as the last line in your gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please also make sure you have in your top level (Project) `build.gradle` file the following Google Services plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```